# GeoServer 2.19.2 WPS plugin crash problem

Tags: geoserver, wps

I installed the WPS plugin yesterday. However, the working system immediately crashed. The site exploded. I am attaching the error logs. The version I am using is 2.19.2. Java version= 1.8.0_302.

The main problem is: When I do not install the WPS plugin, the server is active. The server crashes when I install the WPS plugin. I copy it to the WEB-INF/lib folder and say yes to the replace request. Then the server explodes.

Error Log: https://pastebin.com/5xJKyzRY

**EDİT / SOLVED**

I solved the problem. It is necessary not to replace the serializer-2.7.2.jar file in the WPS Plugin. This time I copied the WEB-INF/lib folder through Filezilla. I can log into the system without any problems. Now I can use it without system crashing.

Comment: It looks as if `/opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc/sf_streams does not exist or is not writable`

Comment: But I'm just exporting the wps-plugin-xxx.zip file to the lib folder. Nothing else I do. Could the files be corrupt? How can I fix this? If I install an older wps plugin on geoserver 2.19.2, will it work? I'm asking before trying this because yesterday the system crashed 2 times and I have to reinstall it.

Comment: No, you must make sure any and all extensions match your GeoServer version number

Comment: @IanTurton I edited and put the error I got when I tried it on localhost in the question section. The plugin version is the same as the geoserver version. Where could I be doing wrong?